# App Crashes When Reading Contacts

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I've got a crash while trying to read the contacts of the user, I thought because it's because of the Emulator, but I want to triple check, as I don't have an android based phone. The Logcat gives an error that, it can't read the row "id" did I incorrectly name that string?

Lastly, how would I implement a dialogue box, to see if the user wants the app to read the contacts?

Thanks so much:)
Code:

```
private void checkandImportContacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_CHECK, 0);
     String checkfirstime = sp.getString("key3", null);
     if(checkfirstime !=null && equals("sdhdasudafdsugdiasgdas38ey98d1diass")) {
         finish();
     } else {
         Cursor cursor = getContacts();
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
               String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
}
     }




private Cursor getContacts() {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = ‘" + ("1") + "’";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+ " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gta5news.bananaphone/com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ‘1’: , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE (in_visible_group = ‘1’) ORDER BY display_name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ‘1’: , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE (in_visible_group = ‘1’) ORDER BY display_name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1520)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.getContacts(ChatService.java:73)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.checkandImportContacts(ChatService.java:56)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.onCreate(ChatService.java:46)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-23 16:49:48.288: E/AndroidRuntime(437):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: what you need? name , number and what else

Comment: @Zapi I'll try and that and other answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong chars in your query

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ‘1’
```

SQLite tries to interpret the `‘1’` as column name since it is no primitive value. Values in SQLite are surrounded by `'`, column names by `"` or nothing.

if that group thing is dynamic do it like this:

```
int group = 1;
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(group) };
```

The value is automatically wrapped in `'` & escaped then. If the value is static you can simply do

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = 1";
String[] selectionArgs = null;
```

Comment: The contacts don't show in the toast? I tried to do a log.e but that doesn't work either.

Comment: If you don't get any error then probably something else is wrong with your query (e.g. there are no contacts with `IN_VISIBLE_GROUP = 1`) or you just don't have contacts at all.

Comment: I don't, as it's the emulator, nor do I have an Android phone.

Comment: You should be able to create contacts on the emulator too (there should be a Contacts app)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getDetails(){
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
        Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexNumber = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        names.moveToFirst();
        do {

            String name   = names.getString(indexName);
            Log.e("Name new:", name);
            String number = names.getString(indexNumber);
            Log.e("Number new:","::"+number);

        } while (names.moveToNext());
    }
```

The above retrun all the name and number from from your contact database..